# Questions on field operator in QFT and interpretations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, commutator

For a real scalar field, I have the following expression for the field operator in momemtum space.

$$\tilde{\phi}(t,\vec{k})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}\left(a_{\vec{k}}e^{-i\omega t}+a^{\dagger}_{-\vec{k}}e^{i\omega t}\right)$$

Why is it that I can discard the phase factors to produce the time independent $\tilde{\phi}(\vec{k})$?

Also, when we speak about the equal time commutation relations, are we looking at the Heisenberg or the Schrodinger picture? Following up, why can we write the equal time commutation relations as time independent?

Moreover, when we speak about the Fock representation in conjunction with the annihilation and creation operators, which picture are we looking at?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that I can discard the phase factors to produce the time independent $\tilde \phi(\vec k)$

The time reference at which Schrödinger picture operators and Heisenberg picture operators are chosen to be equal is often chosen to be $t=0$. Therefore, if $\phi(t,\vec k)$ is the Heisenberg operator, the associated Schrödinger operator is $\phi(\vec k)=  \phi(0,\vec k)$.

> Also, when we speak about the equal time commutation relations, are we looking at the Heisenberg or the Schrodinger picture? Following up, why can we write the equal time commutation relations as time independent?

In the Schrödinger picture, the operators are time-independent, so there are only "commutations relations". When you move to the Heisenberg picture, operators at time $t$ are related to operators at the reference time $t_0$ by a unitary transformation. This means that the Schrödinger picture commutation relation turn into *equal time* commutation relation. Computing the commutation relations between operators at different time requires solving time evolution in some way.

> Moreover, when we speak about the Fock representation in conjunction with the annihilation and creation operators, which picture are we looking at?

Both are possible in principle : the Fock representation is a way to build the Hilbert space for the theory. You can then evolve the state with the Schrödinger equation, or the operators in the Heisenber picture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In QFT, does one usually work with the Heisenberg or Schrodinger picture? This is because I noticed that sometimes $\phi$ is defined with the phase factor and sometimes it is not.

Comment: I think the Heisenberg picture is predominant, mostly because the object we want to compute are correlation functions, for example $\langle \phi(x,t)\phi(x',t')\rangle$, which are easy to write out in the Heisenberg picture, but would require introducing time-evolution operators just to write the down the Schrödinger picture.

Comment: @Thomas in perturbative QFT the [interaction picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture) is more common.